# Laravel Raw Query order by

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a polymorphic relation.

```
Class Reply

public function replyable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Which belongs to `User` and `Trainer`.

When I fetch replies I want an authenticated user's reply placed first.

So, if an auth user is a trainer, trainer's reply should be first and an auth user is a normal user, user's reply should be first.

This is what I got for now.

```
public function index(Question $question)
{
        if (!! trainer()) {
            //if an auth user is a trainer, place their posts first in the response data
            return $question->replies()->orderByRaw("FIELD(replyable_id, ".trainer()->id.") DESC")->inRandomOrder()->with('replyable', 'question')->paginate(15);
        }

        if (auth()->check()) {
            //if an auth user is a normal user, place their posts first in the response data
            return $question->replies()->orderByRaw("FIELD(replyable_id, ".auth()->id().") DESC")->inRandomOrder()->with('replyable', 'question')->paginate(15);
        }

        return $question->replies()->with('replyable', 'question')->inRandomOrder()->paginate(15);
}
```

I need to restraint a query based on `replyable_type`.
So, an auth user is a trainer, replies should be ordered first with a reply which has `replyable_type` of `App\Trainer` with `replyable_id` of whatever the authenticated user (trainer) id is.

This query is not working.

```
 if (!! trainer()) {
            //if an auth user is a trainer, place their posts first in the response data
            return $question->replies()->orderByRaw("where replyable_type = trainers FIELD(replyable_id, ".trainer()->id.") DESC")->inRandomOrder()->with('replyable', 'question')->paginate(15);
        }
```

Comment: `if (!! trainer()) {}`, why?

Comment: ->inRandomOrder() is functioning as expected?

Comment: @NMahurin Yes. The query should fetch replies randomly and be placed **after** an auth user's reply

Comment: Taken from the docs: The inRandomOrder method may be used to sort the query results randomly.